# Information about a laptop fan

Tags: linux, kernel, hardware, acpi, fan

Can you help me with finding **all** the **hardware information** (parameters) and **configuration files** about the **fan** in my laptop? 
I'm interested of the fan's parameters and configuration files that I can edit and change those parameters to have the most possible control over the fan. I used `sudo lshw | grep fan` and it didn't find it.
I remember the sentence "Everything in Unix is a file" so there should be files with the information I'm looking for and commands that are able to extract the information from those files.

Linux kernel communicate with the hardware, so part of the information could be pulled out from there?

[Here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/594074/) is the link to **sensors-detect** output ending with error message.

```
$ dmesg | grep fan
[    0.281316] fan PNP0C0B:00: registered as cooling_device0
[    0.281534] fan PNP0C0B:01: registered as cooling_device1
```

In `/proc/acpi` there is a lot of information. What are the fan parameters I can control (state, speed, scheduling)? And where are the files that I can edit the fan parameters?

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I use Linux OS.

Comment: Have you tried lm-sensors? There is a `sensors-detect` script.

Comment: `sensors-detect` offers me more information than I need. Which information is particularly about the fan (parameters and configuration)?

Comment: @ralf - what is the problem with more information? You can easily pull out the info from sensors-detect. Read http://linux.die.net/man/5/sensors.conf for some guidelines

Comment: @Roly - Which information is related to **fan**? I understood that I can pull out the information but don't know which. Is the information from sensors-detect **all** information about the fan or is there some other information in other configuration files?

Comment: @xralf, you could provide the output of `sensors-detect` from the start and spare me the effort.

Comment: @forcefsck [Here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/594074/) is the link of **sensors-detect** output.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this script, which controls the settings for your model of fan: http://electronpusher.org/~rachel/acerfand

Comment: Could you please explain how this script works? I'm using Acer Travelmate (not Acer Aspire). Is it OK?

Comment: I wasn't saying that this script will solve your problem. I was pointing to this script because it demonstrates how to fiddle with your fans settings. That is, you can learn the commands that you can use to alter various fan settings by reading through the script, and seeing how they did it.

Comment: I haven't found the commands or configuration files that are working on my system. The script uses `/etc/acerfand.conf`, `acer_ec.pl`. I need to be able after this question to find **all** configuration and information about the fan (it doesn't matter if it will be in kernel, but it should be possible to find on every system)

Comment: @xralf It looks like you need to donwload `acer_ec.pl` and create the config file `/etc/acerfad.conf` yourself if you want any custom settings (that file is not required). Of course you don't have it on your system by default, you would have to create it if you want to modify the default behavior of the script. Here are some [instructions](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAcerOne#Quiet_Fan) and downloads for [acer_ec.pl](http://jorge.ulver.no/files/acer_ec.pl) and [acerfand](http://jorge.ulver.no/files/acerfand).

Comment: Thank you, but notice that this is not the exact answer to my question. It means I should look for the configuration files in `acerfand`? If it was a source code it would be possible, but it's a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dmidecode -s
but here is the link what you are REALLY hunting for. [For ALL your information needs...](http://www.secguru.com/article/finding_hardware_details_your_linux_machine_without_using_screw_driver)
Leave a comment if its not a ball park what you are looking for so we can narrow down what it is you actually looking for.

Comment: Thank you but I can't find there nothing about the fan. I'm interested of the fan's parameters and configuration files that I can edit and change those parameters to have the most possible control over the fan. I used `sudo lshw | grep fan` and it didn't find it. But command aren't so important. I remember the sentence "Everything in unix is a file" so there should be files with the information I'm looking for.

Comment: `dmesg` is on a good way. `/proc` seems to have the information inside but I'd like to be able to locate it and be sure that it's all that controls the fan.